# Once i have intergrated the RazorPay with android studio. I only have one payment options. I need more payment options

Tags: kotlin, razorpay

`Now my payment method only can use the card,i want the method like online banking UPI, wallet and so on. But i search in youtube, they all have all the payment
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwK9u.png)

```
try {
        val options = JSONObject()
        options.put("name",username)
        options.put("description","HERBEAUTY")
        //You can omit the image option to fetch the image from the dashboard
        options.put("image","https://s3.amazonaws.com/rzp-mobile/images/rzp.jpg")
        options.put("theme.color", "#FFB8C5");
        options.put("currency","MYR");
        options.put("amount",price*100)//pass amount in currency subunits

        val method = JSONObject()
        method.put("netbanking", 1)
        method.put("upi", 1)
        method.put("card", 1)
        method.put("wallet", 1)
        options.put("checkout", method)

        val prefill = JSONObject()
        prefill.put("email",emailLogin)
        prefill.put("contact",phonenumber)

        options.put("prefill",prefill)
        co.open(this,options)
    }catch (e: Exception){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error in payment: "+ e.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}





i have try this, but not working. `
```

Comment: Is this a recurring payment? If yes, according to their documentation, this is an on-demand feature. You should contact Razor pay to enable it.